# Check window's width function in resize()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check window's width in user visit url and if browser resize then do it again.

Q1. If I only call the function `setcolamt()` in `resize()` it won't do anything `colmat`'s value same as before, I don't know why? I have to pull all code again just like the `comment` then `colmat` will be change.

Q2. Why is `alert()` in `resize()` it will pop up 3 times?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86TDM/2/)

```
var colamt=0;
var winwid = $(window).width();
function setcolamt(){        
    if(winwid > 800){
        colamt = 8;
    }
    else{
        colamt = 4;
    }
};
setcolamt();
alert(colamt);

$(window).resize(function(){
    //var colamt=0;
    //var winwid = $(window).width();
    //function setcolamt(){        
        //if(winwid > 800){
        //    colamt = 8;
        //}
        //else{
        //    colamt = 4;
        //}
    //};
    setcolamt();
    alert(colamt);
});
```

​

Comment: The `alert()` will show for as many times as `window.onresize` was called, which may be _hundreds_ of times on a single action of dragging the window size. It is likely called each time the window size changes by 1px in any direction.

Comment: And why do you say `setcolamt()` only runs if called first outside `.resize()`? A quick test in my console shows that it does run exactly as expected.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I mean if I only write `setcolamt()` in `resize()` after resize browser, the `colamt`'s value wont be update still same as before. I cant figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width does not update after the initial call, because the function `setcolamt()` does not modify the value of `winwid`.

```
var colamt=0;
var winwid = $(window).width();

function setcolamt(){        
    // Get the new winwid
    winwid = $(window).width();
    if(winwid > 800){
        colamt = 8;
    }
    else{
        colamt = 4;
    }
};
```

Unless you intend to use `winwid` outside `setcolamt()`, it is not necessary to declare it at the global scope. Instead you can just declare and use it in the function

```
function setcolamt(){        
    // declare winwid here with var, not outside.
    // and no need to call $(window).width() outside...
    var winwid = $(window).width();
    if(winwid > 800){
        colamt = 8;
    }
    else{
        colamt = 4;
    }
};
```

[Here is the updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86TDM/3/) (using `console.log()` instead of annoying `alert()`)

Answer (score 2):

move `var winwid = $(window).width();` into `setcolamt()`.
But note to remove `alert()` before check. it maybe hung. `console.log` is better than it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put *var winwid = $(window).width();*  inside setcolamt();
2. Not care about how many alert, since resize will trigger for many times. Use console.log() instead.

Answer (score 0):

`var winwid = $(window).width();` will only set itself once, as it is currently written.  On the resize event, you need to watch for the updated size of the window.  One quick way would be to move the `var winwid = $(window).width()` into the function.  Another is grabbing the new width from the event passed to your .resize() callback function.